# EXCEL Sum amount based on matching order numbers in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working on a spreadsheet to track our general ledger account for inventory in transit.  There is a debit to the account when the order is shipped and a credit when it is received.  Column C is the post amount and Column L is the order number.  I want a formula that will look for matching order numbers in Column L and if the order nets to zero in Column C, return the comment "cleared" to Column A.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Super User where we are all volunteers helping you when you've tried to accomplish something on your own and get stuck. This is not a script writing service. Please [edit] your question to include what you have attempted and where it fails. We can help you from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(SUMIFS($E:$E,$D:$D,B2)=0,"cleared","not cleared")
```

This is my setup:

[image]